# The loop does not come out

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to get a result that if i use a for loop then 'Monster' comes out 10 times.But 'Monster' came out continually. Could you tell me What the problem is?
Thank you for reading to the end:)

```
private static void fight() {

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    while (user.isalive() && enemy.isalive()) {
        user.attack(enemy);
        if ( !enemy.isalive() ) break; 
        enemy.attack(user);
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }

    if (user.isalive()) {
        System.out.println("The monster is dead.");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        user.money+=enemy.money;

//            System.out.println(player.money);
            System.out.println("I got 100 won");
            System.out.println("total won : "+user.money+"won");
                     enemy.hp=50;

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("I'm dead and the game is over.");
        break;
    }return;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the return statement at the end of the if-else. The return is inside the loop, and that is possibly the reason